# Check if LI has "parent" LI using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, traversal

I'm working on the comments section of a WP theme, and the styling requires the use of some clever jQuery in order to make it work right... However, when trying to style admin comments in a long nested UL, I'm having trouble traversing the DOM with jQuery to find the elements I need to adjust the CSS for...

Here's what I've tried using:

```
$('.commentlist li.admin').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parents('li').size() > 0 ) {
    //Has parent LI, so this is a child comment
    $(this).children('.avatar').css({'background-position':'right -2530px'});
    $(this).children('.avatar img').css({'border-right':'1px solid #fff','border-bottom':'1px solid #fff'});
  }
  else {
    //Has no parent LI, top level comment
    $(this).children('.avatar').css({'background-position':'0 -2530px'});
    $(this).children('.avatar img').css({'border-right':'1px solid #fff','border-bottom':'1px solid #fff'});
  }
});
```

Basically I want to apply certain styles to elements within "top level" LI elements with the class "admin", and apply another set of styles to elements within "nested" LI elements with the class "admin".

I thought that by checking to see if an LI element had a parent LI then that would be a quick way to do it, but I'm apparently going about it the wrong way...

Any ideas?

PS- Here's a sample of my HTML structure:

```
            <ul class="commentlist">
            <li>
                <div class="border-fake">
                    <div class="comment-header">
                        <small>3rd may, 2009</small>
                        <div class="rank rank2"></div>
                    </div><!--/comment-header-->
                    <div class="comment-body">
                        <div class="avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b3be63a4c2a439b013787725dfce802?s=61" />
                        </div><!--/avatar-->
                        <h4 class="comment-author">Joe Bloggs</h4>
                        <small class="author-url">ohmygodisuck.me</small>
                        <div class="clearit"></div>
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                            <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                        </div><!--/comment-text-->
                        <div class="reply">
                            <a href="#">reply</a>
                        </div><!--/reply-->
                    </div><!--/comment-body-->
                </div><!--/border-fake-->
            </li>
            <li class="admin">
                <div class="border-fake">
                    <div class="comment-header">
                        <small>3rd may, 2009</small>
                        <div class="rank rankadmin"></div>
                    </div><!--/comment-header-->
                    <div class="comment-body">
                        <div class="avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e610fd44bdd000891b3a67a22d1676b7?s=61" />
                        </div><!--/avatar-->
                        <h4 class="comment-author">Jamie Carter</h4>
                        <small class="author-url">jamiecarter.me</small>
                        <div class="clearit"></div>
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                            <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                        </div><!--/comment-text-->
                        <div class="reply">
                            <a href="#">reply</a>
                        </div><!--/reply-->
                    </div><!--/comment-body-->
                </div><!--/border-fake-->
                <ul class="children">
                    <li>
                        <div class="border-fake">
                            <div class="comment-header">
                                <small>3rd may, 2009</small>
                                <div class="rank rank4"></div>
                            </div><!--/comment-header-->
                            <div class="comment-body">
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b3be63a4c2a439b013787725dfce802?s=44" />
                                </div><!--/avatar-->
                                <div class="comment-text">
                                    <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet. Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                                    <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet. Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                                    <div class="clearit"></div>
                                    <h4 class="comment-author">Weird Guy</h4>
                                    <small class="author-url">howdydoo.com</small>
                                </div><!--/comment-text-->
                                <div class="reply">
                                    <a href="#">reply</a>
                                </div><!--/reply-->
                            </div><!--/comment-body-->
                        </div><!--/border-fake-->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="border-fake">
                            <div class="comment-header">
                                <small>3rd may, 2009</small>
                                <div class="rank rank1"></div>
                            </div><!--/comment-header-->
                            <div class="comment-body">
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b3be63a4c2a439b013787725dfce802?s=44" />
                                </div><!--/avatar-->
                                <div class="comment-text">
                                    <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                                    <p>Amet! Ut aliquam tempor sit tempor. In, placerat, mattis mid porta pid? Vut ut tincidunt ac, porta placerat nisi auctor elit? Dignissim vel! Amet.</p>
                                    <div class="clearit"></div>
                                    <h4 class="comment-author">Jimbo Wilson</h4>
                                    <small class="author-url">countrybumpkin.com</small>
                                </div><!--/comment-text-->
                                <div class="reply">
                                    <a href="#">reply</a>
                                </div><!--/reply-->
                            </div><!--/comment-body-->
                        </div><!--/border-fake-->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And just for good measure, here's an online demo so you can see what's going on and what's not... http://joshjones.me/comment-test/

Comment: Just a sec and I'll post up a sample..

Comment: Unless I'm badly misunderstanding requirements this seems like something you should be able to handle with straight CSS.

Comment: I could, but the amount of times I would have to redeclare the css styles for each element as it cascades would be ridiculous... I was able to make it work 3 levels deep, but past that, trying to style admin comments and then children of admin comments and child admin comments of admin comments got to be a bit on the bloated side...

Comment: I mean define a style that applies to the first level `li` elements, and a different style that only applies to second+ level `li` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the nested ones are all under the `.children` class, right?

So why not something like this:

```
ul.commentlist > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar {
    background-position: right -2530px;
}
ul.commentlist > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar > img {
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

ul.children .avatar {
    background-position:0 -2530px;
}
ul.children .avatar > img {
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It would seem as though your 4 unique selector pairs would be:

```
    <!-- Top level non-admin -->
ul.commentlist > li > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar
ul.commentlist > li > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar > img

    <!-- Top level admin ( should override non-admin ) -->
ul.commentlist > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar
ul.commentlist > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar > img

    <!-- Nested level non-admin -->
ul.children > li > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar
ul.children > li > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar > img

    <!-- Nested level admin ( should override non-admin ) -->
ul.children > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar
ul.children > li.admin > .border-fake > .comment-body > .avatar > img
```

The ones with the `.admin` class should override the ones without.

Comment: Yes, I could do it with CSS... However, as I stated in a previous comment, the css gets extremely bloated when I have to redeclare the styles for non-admin versus admin in the different nested levels.

That's why I decided to try to do it with jQuery instead.

I've posted an online example so everyone can see what I'm talking about: http://joshjones.me/comment-test/

Comment: @Josh - So you have 3 style types: 1. top level admin, 2. nested admin, 3. all the others. Is that right?

Comment: Actually there are 4...

1. Top level non-admin
2. Top level admin
3. Child non-admin
4. Child admin

Comment: @Josh - I updated my answer. I think it should work given your HTML structure.

Comment: Ok, the second solution you posted works on 1st and 2nd level comments... but past that they simply use the style of whatever the parent level is using... I've updated the demo: http://joshjones.me/comment-test/

Comment: @Josh - I think I see. Could you please point me to a couple of the avatars that are not styled properly? Also, could you give your non-admin ones a class like `.nonadmin`? I assume it is the ones without a class that are being overridden by a parent `.admin`.

Comment: Any comments that have green alien heads in the top right corner should have the admin styling (silver bg behind avatar image)... Whereas the rest should all have normal styling (dark gray bg behind avatar image)

Comment: I've also added  `class="non-admin"` to all LI elements that aren't already classified as "admin"

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot... I had missed adding the admin class to 2 of the child elements. Thanks a ton dude, you've saved me hours of headaches!

Comment: So, for example, the last appearance of "Josh Jones" which is under "Weird Guy" should have a silver border, right?

Comment: I was just about to mention that "Josh Jones" didn't have an admin class. Glad you found it. :o)